# Sorting integers with .sort()

Tags: python, sorting

```
numbers = list(input("Please enter some numbers: ").split(" "))

numbers.sort()
print(numbers)
```

Can someone explain to me why this code only sorts the first half of the inputted numbers?
See scenario below.

Input:

```
Please enter some numbers: 39 28 374 39 20 2 4 58
```

Output:

```
['2', '20', '28', '374', '39', '39', '4', '58']
```

I expected all the numbers to be sorted in ascending order.

Comment: You're sorting strings, not integers.

Comment: every input is string in python.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're inputting and trying to sort them as strings. Instead, you should convert them to integers before sorting.

```
numbers = input("Please enter some numbers: ").split(" ")
numbers = [int(i) for i in numbers]

numbers.sort()
print(numbers)
```

Comment: for number in numbers:
    number = int(number)                                                                                                                     I tried this before, but this did not work out. Do you know why?

Comment: Surely this ground is covered on SO already? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66855797/sort-method-returning-incorrect-output)  or in some other question's answers...?

Comment: @AbishaBindar without context of how it did not work I cannot say.

Comment: I understand. Thanks a lot.